# conditional entropy when conditioning on RV and event

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables and let $A$ be an event. I'm trying to figure out which one of the two definitions is the correct one for the conditional entropy, as this isn't clear to me from the standard definition (which doesn't consider conditioning on additional events). It seems to me that either of the following two could be the right interpretation:
$$
H[ X \mid Y,A ] = \sum_y p(y) H[ X \mid Y=y,A],
$$
$$
H[ X \mid Y,A ] = \sum_y p(y \mid A) H[ X \mid Y=y,A].
$$

I'm leaning towards the latter definition because the conditioning on event $A$ restricts the joint probability space from which we are sampling $X$ and $Y$. However, I can't formalize this intuition and, as mentioned, I'm not even sure if it is correct!

Comment: Where did you encounter this notation?

Comment: I didn't encounter it anywhere. I was reading about the standard definition of conditional entropy, which is defined as $H[ X \mid Y] = \sum_y p(y) H[ X \mid  Y=y]$ and I was wondering how this generalizes to the setting where we also condition on some event, e.g., $A$ could be the event $X \ge Y$.

Comment: But then you're free to define it any way you want; it doesn't make sense to ask which is the "correct" definition or the "right interpretation" if no one else is using this notation. Both definitions are circular, though; you're using the symbol being defined on both sides of the equation.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the right-hand side as it was confusing. Does the question make more sense now?

Comment: Well, the first part of my comment stands. If you haven't seen this anywhere (I haven't, either), what keeps you from defining this notation as whatever you want? The second version makes more sense to me than the first. If I saw this notation, I would think it means either your second version, or

$$
\sum_y\sum_{B\in\{A,\overline A\}}p(Y=y\cap B)H[X\mid Y=y,B]\;.
$$

The comma between $Y$ and $A$ seems to imply that $Y$ and $A$ are being treated similarly (despite being a variable and an event). It's a bit unfortunate that $H[X\mid Y]$ uses $\mid$ differently than e.g. $E[X \mid Y]$.

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem if $H[X\mid Y]$ were used like $E[X\mid Y]$ is; then what's currently denoted as $H[X\mid Y]$ would be written $E[H[X\mid Y]]$, and you could unambiguously write your first version as $E_YH[X\mid Y,A]$ and your second version as $E_Y[H[X\mid Y,A]\mid A]$. But I can't imagine in which scenario the first version could be useful. The second version seems more natural; it's just the usual conditional entropy, conditioned as a whole on $A$.